# IDEA seems incognisant of the Servlet API 3.0 xml schema, nevertheless my web-app deploys ok?

Tags: intellij-idea, xsd, servlet-3.0

[image: web.xml]

I am able to deploy my web-application from IDEA without problems using annotation-based url-mappings, so why does IDEA nevertheless highlight the  tag as a violation of the schema-definition here?

(using IDEA 12.1.4, Tomcat 7)

Comment: +1 for using and spelling incognisant correctly :)

Comment: Can you check that IntelliJ has got the correct schema for this? You can drill into it by pressing ctrl-b on the string ending with .xsd

Comment: Great tip! I didn't know IDEA let you jump to it's schema definitions. Hitherto it was always black magic what it validated against. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IDEA is validating your XML according to the schema and it is correctly saying that `Element metadata-complete is not allowed here`.

If you look at the schema `web-app_3.0.xsd` you'll see that it imports `web-commmon_3.0.xsd`. And this `web-common` schema has defined `metadata-complete` to be part of the `web-common-attributes`.

```
<xsd:attributeGroup name="web-common-attributes">
  <xsd:attribute name="version"
                 type="javaee:web-app-versionType"
                 use="required"/>
  <xsd:attribute name="id"
                 type="xsd:ID"/>
  <xsd:attribute name="metadata-complete"
                 type="xsd:boolean">
    ...
```

In summary this means that `metadata-complete` is an **attribute** to `web-app` element.

Change your xml to this instead:

```
<?xml version=1.0 encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3.0.xsd"
         version="3.0"
         metadata-complete="false">

    <display-name>Hello World</display-name>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much.  The xml was lifted out of an [Apress book](http://www.apress.com/9781430237235). I should have questioned it, given the state of editorial in software publishing.

Comment: Oh ... and I was also able to read in the web-common_3.0.xsd why the app deploys happily regardless:      `If metadata-complete is not specified or is set to
          "false", the deployment tool must examine the class
          files of the application for annotations, as
          specified by the specifications.`